# In OpenMP, how does static scheduling work when the number of threads don't divide evenly into the number of iterations in a parallel for loop?

Tags: multithreading, openmp, scheduling

I understand the general idea behind how static scheduling works, but one situation that confuses me is when, in an OpenMP parallel for loop with static scheduling, a given chunk size, and a given number of threads, how will the compiler distribute the iterations among the threads if the number of threads does not divide equally into the number of iterations?

For example:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4) schedule(static, 2)
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

Here, there is a parallel for loop with 4 threads, 10 iterations, and a static schedule with chunk size 2. Will the compiler distribute the iterations such that the number of iterations for each respective thread will look something like 3-3-2-2? Or can it be any kind of distribution such as 2-2-3-3, 2-3-2-3, 3-2-2-3, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The section 2.9.2 of the [OpenMP 5.0 specification](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5.0.pdf) states:

> When `kind` is `static`, iterations are divided into chunks of size `chunk_size`, and the chunks are assigned to the threads in the team in a **round-robin fashion in the order of the thread number**. Each chunk contains `chunk_size` iterations, except for the chunk that contains the sequentially last iteration, which may have fewer iterations. When no `chunk_size` is specified, the iteration space is divided into chunks that are approximately equal in size, and at most one chunk is distributed to each thread. The size of the chunks is unspecified in this case.

Thus, the result in this case is 4-2-2-2.

Comment: A follow up question I have would be are the 4 iterations of the first thread next to each other? Like, will they all take place consecutively, or will the first 2 iterations happen first and the last 2 iterations happen after the last thread? I believe that they will all take place consecutively, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: The 2 first and last iterations will be executed by the first thread due to the round-robin distribution. Thus, no, all the iterations of a threads are not contiguous if you use `schedule(static,2)` (only consecutive pairs). Here is an example of execution: `{(t=0,i=0) ; (t=0,i=1) ; (t=0,i=8) ; (t=0,i=9) ; (t=3,i=6) ; (t=3,i=7) ; (t=1,i=2) ; (t=1,i=3) ; (t=2,i=4) ; (t=2,i=5)}` with `t` the thread id and `i` the iteration id.